# A variant of sheaves for which the Cech complex is exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, higher-category-theory

This is a very naive question. Suppose we have a site $\mathcal C$ (we can just think of a topological space with it's open sets) and a cover in it $\cup_\alpha X_\alpha = X$, Then, given a presheaf of abelian groups $\mathscr F$ on $\mathcal C$, we can form the Cech complex with respect to the cover:
$$0 \to \mathscr F(X) \to \prod_\alpha \mathscr F(X_\alpha) \to \prod_{\alpha,\beta} \mathscr F(X_\alpha \times_X X_\beta) \to \dots $$
where the maps are the alternating restriction maps.

We say $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf if the first homology of the above complex is $\mathscr F(X)$ for all covers. Is there a terminology for those presheaves $\mathscr F$ for which the entire complex is exact? What about if we only require the first $n$ terms to be exact? Are there interesting examples of such things?

In the case of an affine scheme with each open in the cover being affine (or a contractible nice space with a good open cover (all intersections are contractible), every quasi coherent sheaf automatically makes the complex exact. But how about other, more interesting examples?

Comment: Some nitpicks: your use of the phrase "the entire complex is exact" may need some refinement. If you literally mean that, then all homology is zero, so $\mathcal{F}(X)=0$, which does not agree with your final paragraph ("in the case of an affine scheme ... every sheaf automatically makes the complex exact"). Perhaps you mean that the complex is exact everywhere _except the first entry_? (This statement about affine schemes is also false unless you enforce quasi-coherence of the sheaves.) Also, you need to take direct products instead of direct sums in your definition of the Cech complex.

Comment: The last sentence is false even with @KReiser adjustment. For affine scheme, you should at least consider quasi-coherent sheaves otherwise you can easily construct counter-example. But even then, I don't think it is true in full generality (for example if the $X_\alpha$ are not affine themselves). It is also wrong for contractible nice space (take $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathcal{F}=i_*\mathbb{Z}$ where $i:S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is the inclusion). In fact, it also fails for the constant sheaf on $\mathbb{R}^2$ !

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! I did mean to include $\mathscr F(X)$ in the complex! and in the affine case, I did mean to only talk about affine covers and q-coh sheaves!

Comment: What is exactly the condition here ? I thought it was "for any open $U$ and any cover $\{U_i\}$ of $U$, the Cech complex is exact. If you add assumptions on $U$ (always the whole space) or on the cover, you have something rather specific. On the other hand, without restrictions on $U$ and on the cover, I am not sure a single (non trivial) sheaf works.

Comment: I guess I am thinking about it as a condition for all opens $U$ and all covers $U_i$. Don't all quasi coherent sheaves on an affine space satisfy this condition?

Comment: @Asvin (Sorry for my late respond, somehow I don't get the notification). No all quasi-coherent sheaf satisfy this condition on an affine scheme because there are open subsets which are not affine. For such open subset $U$, there is a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ which has non vanishing cohomology. Then for the sheaf $j_*\mathcal{F}$ (where $j:U\to X$ is the inclusion), the Cech complex associated to $U$ and to an affine cover of $U$ cannot be exact since it has cohomology.

Comment: But there is something even worse. Even if $X$ is affine, there might exist a cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ such that the Cech complex is not exact. Indeed, the vanishing of cohomology says that the colimit over all covers is zero, but a given cover might yield a non exact Cech complex. I don't have a counterexample in this context, but I have a counterexample of a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the Cech complex for the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ is non exact.

Comment: Áh, I see. I was implicitly thinking only about the affine site, ie covers where everything is affine. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: But that's a good point. Maybe the condition is simply too strong in general. I would be interested in the example about R2 you mentioned! @roland

Comment: I believe the following works : let $U_1$ be the set of points whose distance to the origin is in $(2,3)$. Let $U_2=(-1,+\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$ and $U_3=(-\infty,1)\times\mathbb{R}$. (Draw a picture). You have $\check{C}^0$ of rank 3, $\check{C}^1$ of rank 3 and $\check{C}^2$ of rank 2. The augmented Cech complex cannot be exact for rank consideration.

Comment: That's a nice example!!